# multilingual php

Tags: php

I want to save the values from different languages like arabic, chinese etc into variables and post these values to a different page. the values are not posting correctly. I mean these should be in a same language in which they are stored.
Anyone help me.
thanks in advance

Comment: where that values will be stored? files or database? or they will just passed to script for output (without saving)? Use UTF-8 charset in headers and for your scripts.

Comment: @user321038: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_QRTIiPKZXJU/R0z0jE_F3TI/AAAAAAAAACE/55uOMt4VTZA/s320/shrek_catKopie.jpg

Comment: I would recommend using a framework such as CakePHP that can do this for you.  Seems you need all the help you can get.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be fair to re-state your question as follows?

I want to take text input in Arabic or Chinese from a web form and render it in a new web page, but right now the rendered text looks wrong. How can I render the text correctly?

If this is what you're asking, then you're probably about to learn a lot more than you already know about character encodings. If not, then you really need to be more specific about what you're doing (as per the comment from OZ_).